# Как сделать маску для ie edge или clip-path?

Tags: css, css3, svg

Добрый день, мне нужно сделать маску для изображения, но ie edge не понимает это свойство: `clip-path: polygon(0 0,100% 15%,100% 100%,0 85%);`
Я прочитал что можно сделать с помощью svg, но я не понимаю как мне сам объект создать, какие размеры указывать и как.
Маска должна выглядеть вот так:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Обратите внимание на `clipPathUnits="objectBoundingBox"` — благодаря этому атрибуту точки обрезания задаются относительно: 1 = 100%, .1 = 10%.

```html
<svg width=100% height=300>
  <defs>
    <clipPath id="clip" clipPathUnits="objectBoundingBox">
      <polygon points="0,0 1,.1 1,1 0,.9"></polygon>
    </clipPath>
  </defs>
  <image xlink:href="http://placeimg.com/500/300/any" clip-path="url(#clip)" width=500 height=300 />
</svg>
```

Comment: Thx! I will try to use it.

Comment: Можно ли передать в clip-path='url()' класс а не идентификатор, например у меня будет не одна маска, например 4, 4 одинаковых id не покатит, можно конечно увеличивать id на один но тогда придется и в image clip-path='url(величивать id на один) я глянул что clip-path можно использовать как правило css и не добавлять его в html с привязкой на маску

Comment: `clip-path` может быть не только атрибутом в свг, но и использоваться как свойство css, но вы вроде бы хотели наоборот отказаться от него в css потому, что поддержка браузерами вас не устраивает. Созданную область обрезания можно применять к любому количеству свг-объектов, если я правильно понял вопрос.

Comment: да, просто сейчас в <clipPath уазан id='clip'> а далее идет <image clip-path='url(#clip)'> могу лия указать вместо id например класс clip и в css ссылаться не на id а на класс, допустим сейчас я сделал вот так image{clip-path: url(#clip);} можно лли предать туда image{clip-path: url(.cilp);} как-то так?

Answer (score 0):

Примерно так:

[Demo JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/f8tcxooy/)

```css
body {
  background-color: #e0e0e0;
}

#image-wrapper {
  position: relative;
}

.svg-background,
.svg-image {
  clip-path: url(#clip-triangle);
}

.svg-image {
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease 0.2s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease 0.2s;
  opacity: 1;
  transition: all 0.5s ease 0.2s;
}

svg.clip-svg {
  height: 250px;
  position: absolute;
  width: 250px;
}

#svg-1 {
  left: 0px;
  top: 0px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div id="image-wrapper">
    <svg id="svg-1" class="clip-svg">
            <rect class='svg-background' width="300" height="300" fill="#ffffff" />
            <image id="img-1" class='svg-image' width="300" height="300" xlink:href="http://25.media.tumblr.com/tumblr_m5nre6cxkQ1qbs7p5o1_r1_500.jpg" />
        </svg>
  </div>
  <svg id="svg-defs">
        <defs>
            <clipPath id="clip-triangle">
                <polygon points="0 0, 100 0, 112 13, 240 13, 240 250, -250 250"/>
            </clipPath>
        </defs>
    </svg>
```

Comment: в вашем коде блок обрезается при помощи свойства `clip-path`: `.svg-background, .svg-image { clip-path: url(#clip-triangle); }`